# Finding column index of a PyTorch tensor that has most 1's

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a `PyTorch` tensor `a` shaped like below:

```
import torch
a = torch.tensor([[[1., 0., 0., 0.]],
        [[0., 1., 0., 0.]],
        [[1., 0., 0., 0.]],
        [[0., 0., 0., 1.]],
        [[1., 0., 0., 0.]],
        [[0., 0., 0., 1.]],
        [[1., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

Each row of the tensor `a` has 4 elements, 1's and 0's. Say I index the row and the column of this tensor accordingly. So for instance, the entry in the row 0 (uppermost row) is `[[1., 0., 0., 0.]]`, whereas the entry in the column 3 (rightmost column) is `[[0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.]]`.

From a given tensor, I want to identify the index of the column where `1.` appear most frequently. For example, for the tensor `a`, the index of such a column would be 0. If there are ties in the number of 1.'s, I still would like to get all of those tied column indices.

How can I do this task easily on Python?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your matrix only contains 0 and 1, you can sum the elements of each column and then search for the sum that is the largest:

```
import numpy as np

% sum over columns
sumsi = torch.sum(a, dim=1)

% find where maximum
col_idx = np.where(sumsi==np.max(sumsi))
```

Comment: if you only need one entry, use np.argmax

Comment: ahh true. i keep forgetting this function XD